# Upgrading PHP within a docker container

Tags: docker, php

So I have a docker container running a PHP 7.2.34 service as follows:-

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:

 #PHP Service
 app:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  image: digitalocean.com/php
  container_name: app
  ...
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm
...
```

Rather than restart Nginx I simply restart the containers like:-

```
docker stop app db webserver
docker rm app db webserver
docker-compose up -d
```

I'd like to upgrade to PHP 7.4+ or even 8. I tried to simply replace `FROM php:7.2-fpm` with `FROM php:7.4-fpm` but `phpinfo()` reports no change in PHP version? Does: `image: digitalocean.com/php` have any significance when upgrading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command will update your image and force stop and recreate the containers:

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build
```

To verify run `docker exec -it app php -v` this will return the php version info.

```
# The new image name when running `docker-compose up/build`
image: digitalocean.com/php
```

***Explanation***:

The command `docker-compose up` will build an image only it's not exist. 
To force build new image add `--build` flag or do `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up`

[Reference here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

> If you want to force Compose to stop and recreate all containers, use the `--force-recreate` flag.

> `--build`                    Build images before starting containers.

Comment: I tried this one first as it was the most complete in explanation. It works, thanks. I ran into a collection of PHP extension errors with the 7.4 build - but that's another issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between docker images and docker containers.
See `docker image ls` and `docker container ls`.

To rebuild the image and create a container run

`docker-compose up -d --build`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are stopping application anyway you can remove all images from your host with:

```
docker-compose down --rmi all
```

then start app with recreation of containers as @Shmuel advised

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Dockerfile for the destination version for example

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
```

or

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm
```

and you adjust your library with [this document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php) for 7.xxx

or for 7.xxx to 8.xxx [this document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.php)

Comment: These documents seem to explain changes like new and deprecated functionalities, but I don't with a quick view find instructions on how to adjust a library. Could you please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/672219/edit) your answer to clarify? [From Review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro)

Comment: do you have a log by the command docker log?